# Reduce width of major mode column in Helm?

Tags: helm

Is there a way to make the major mode column in `helm` narrower? See image below; the major mode names are taking up a lot of space, while the file paths are cut off.

[image: Helm major mode width]

There's `helm-buffer-max-length` for buffer names (which, ironically, I'd never want to cut off), but nothing for the major mode that I could find.

Comment: How do you know it's not the buffer name column?

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/pull/1311) can reduce the major mode name width a bit, though I am not sure if it is enough to you.

Comment: @wasamasa What do you mean? The buffer names are restricted to 20 characters by default.

Comment: Disregard this, I've just noticed that the buffer name column is followed by a size column, so it can't be that.

Comment: After that PR got merged, the width of major mode column is (2 space + the length of longest major mode name), I think it is reasonable. Also note: some boring buffers are hidden initially, use `C-c a` to view them, since some major mode name there is very long.